# Consulta para ver cantidad de artículos sin venta por día. SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

quien me pudiera ayudar con este query, estoy intentado  realizar un reporte que me traiga todos los artículos de una empresa y muestre su venta por día, sea que haya tenido o no y al final me haga un conteo de los cantidad de artículos que NO se vendieron.

```
select 
 fec_lote as fecha,
 co_prov as Proveedor,
 a.co_art,
 art_des,
 isnull(sum(pendiente),0) as cant_venta
from 
 art as a
 full outer join
 reng_fac as rf on a.co_art = rf.co_art 
where 
 fec_lote = '20210111' 
group by rf.fec_lote, a.co_art, a.art_des, a.co_prov
order by 1,2, 5 desc
```

Si no filtro la fecha, no hay ningún problema, me trae todos los articulos, se hayan vendido o no, el problema radica cuando le filtro una fecha, ya que al hacer esto, solo me trae los articulos que SI se vendieron ese dia, y los que no, simplemente no los trae la consulta

Cabe destacar que **art** es la tabla de articulos y **reng_fac** es la tabla donde están los renglones de las facturas y dice la fecha de  venta, cantidad de articulos vendidos, etc, etc.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿MySql o SQL Server? A cuál etiqueta le creo? Y por qué mysqli si no tienes código PHP en tu pregunta?

Comment: Si, lo siento, es solo sql sever

Comment: Dale, no hay lío. La duda es: estás seguro que para esa fecha hay artículos que no se vendieron? Con qué datos podríamos probar tu consulta para ver qué es lo que hace mal? (podrías incluir la definición de las tablas y algunos datos de prueba, por favor?) Además, si `fec_lote` es de la tabla `reng_fac` (estoy adivinando porque no sé cómo serán tus tablas), efectivamente no hay cómo mostrar registros de `art` que tengan ese valor nulo :)

Comment: ¿Entonces solo quieres de una fecha en específico o de un rango de fechas? Porque la solución es distinta.

Answer (score 1):

El escenario que indicas.

```
Create table art (co_Art int, art_des varchar(100), co_prov int);
Create table reng_fac (fec_lote date, pendiente float, co_art int);
go
Insert into art (co_Art, art_des, co_prov)
values 
(1,'articulo 1',1),
(2,'articulo 2',1),
(3,'articulo 3',1),
(4,'articulo 4',2);
go
Insert into reng_fac(fec_lote, pendiente, co_art)
values
('20210111',5,1),
('20210111',7,1),
('20210111',10,1),
('20210111',5,4),
('20210111',10,4);
go
```

4 artículos, de los cuáles solo dos han tenido operaciones para el día a filtrar.

```
declare @fec_lote date ='20210101';
;With articulos as (
    select * from art
), renglones as (
    Select  fec_lote as fecha,
            isnull(sum(pendiente),0) as cant_venta,
            rf.co_art
        from reng_fac rf 
        where (rf.fec_lote = @fec_lote or @fec_lote is null)
    group by rf.co_art, rf.fec_lote
)
select 
        rf.fecha,
        co_prov as Proveedor,
        a.co_art as co_Art,
        art_des,
        isNull(rf.cant_venta,0) as cant_venta
        from 
         articulos as a left join renglones
          as rf on a.co_art = rf.co_art;
```

Utilizando una tabla de expresión común correlativa, podemos ir por partes. Primero leemos los artículos, en este caso todos.

En el conjunto 2 leemos los renglones y agrupamos la suma de unidades vendidas por co_art. Y ahí le añadimos al filtro, la fecha que tenemos en la variable declarada o si esta es nula, que traiga todos los datos por fecha de lote y artículo (sumando pendiente).

Luego en la salida de la segunda tabla de expresión común, mezclamos ambos conjuntos con un left join, porque supongo que no cabe la posibilidad de tener ventas de artículos que no existan.

[image: Resultado]

[Tablas de expresión común correlativas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-2-correlativos/)